# Can I take a screenshot of a virtual console?

Tags: virtual-console

Is there a way for me to take a screenshot in a virtual console?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There's an application called `fbgrab` provided by the `fbcat` package that (as the name might suggest) grabs a shot of the current framebuffer. This *might* not work on newer KMS setups.

```
sudo apt-get install fbcat
fbgrab screenshot.png
```

If that fails, you could always use a VM in VirtualBox.

---

If you want to take a picture of *another* TTY, `fbgrab` takes a `-c N` argument (where `N` is replaced with the `/dev/ttyN` you're using).

So if you wanted tty1:

```
sudo fbgrab -c 1 Desktop/tty-screenshot.png
```

Comment: When I try `fbgrab foo.png` it says `Error: Couldn't open /dev/fb0.`. Any idea why?

Comment: @trusktr I know this is late, but it may be because you aren't in the video group. Try editing the file /etc/group, and adding your username to the end of the line that starts with "video". If that doesn't work, try using the app as root

Comment: @B1KMusic Thanks, I'll have to try it when my new laptop arrives next week. I have Windows in the interim.

Comment: I had to use `sudo -E fbgrab vt1.png`. But it worked great.

Comment: The best answer so far and it worked!

Answer (score 19):

To take a screenshot of the first virtual console (AKA *screendump*) and save it to a file called "screenshot":

```
sudo cat /dev/vcs1 > screenshot
```

Using this method, the screenshots are saved in plain text format, not an image (check this with `file` or `mimetype` command). It simply outputs a screen dump and then EOF. Note that the output **does not** contain  newline characters, so some processing may be required:

```
sudo cat /dev/vcs1 | fold  > screenshot
```

`fold` wrap each input line to fit in specified width (80 by default).

You cannot take the screenshot of a virtual console when graphics is enabled.

### Reference

- [VCS: vcs, vcsa - virtual console memory](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/vcs.4.html)

Comment: what do you mean text format? The RGB values are saved in a text file, or the text contents of the terminal is saved? Usually people want a screenshot to capture some visual bug which doesn't transfer to encoded character output.