# How to take screenshot in a TTY terminal

Tags: screenshot, tty

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I take a screenshot of a virtual console?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12208/can-i-take-a-screenshot-of-a-virtual-console)

I sometimes go to TTY1 to do some fixing when an app freezes or the system is slow (rare cases) but in some cases I need to take a screenshot of the TTY terminal. Is there an app, command or shortcut that can help me take a screenshot of the TTY terminal?

Comment: [Can I take a screenshot of a virtual console?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/12208/can-i-take-a-screenshot-of-a-virtual-console)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first install a "third party program" [snapscreenshot](http://bisqwit.iki.fi/source/snapscreenshot.html) .

Hence to install snapscreenshot,you have to manually download the latest program tar ball source and compile:

```
noah:~# cd /usr/local/src
noah:/usr/local/src# wget -q http://bisqwit.iki.fi/src/arch/snapscreenshot 1.0.14.3.tar.bz2
noah:/usr/local/src# tar -jxvvvf snapscreenshot-1.0.14.3.tar.bz2
…
noah:/usr/local/src# cd snapscreenshot-1.0.14.3
noah:/usr/local/src/snapscreenshot-1.0.14# ./configure && make && make install
Configuring…
Fine. Done. make.
make: Nothing to be done for `all'.
if [ ! "/usr/local/bin" = "" ];
 then mkdir –parents /usr/local/bin 2>/dev/null;
 mkdir /usr/local/bin 2>/dev/null;
for s in snapscreenshot "";
 do if [ ! "$s" = "" ]; 
then
install -c -s -o bin -g bin -m 755 "$s" /usr/local/bin/"$s";
fi;
done;
fi;
if [ ! "/usr/local/man" = "" ]; 
then mkdir –parents /usr/local/man 2>/dev/null;
 mkdir /usr/local/man 2>/dev/null;
for s in snapscreenshot.1 ""; 
do if [ ! "$s" = "" ]; 
then
install -m 644 "$s" /usr/local/man/man"`echo "$s"|sed 's/.*.//'`"/"$s";
fi;
done;
fi
```

By default snapscreenshot command is made to take screenshot in a tga image format, this format is readable by most picture viewing programs available today, however it is not too common and not so standartized for the web as the JPEG and PNG.

For more info check [this](http://pc-freak.net/blog/how-to-make-screenshot-in-devtty-console-on-gnu-linux-taking-picture-jpeg-png-snapshot-of-text-console-in-systems-without-graphical-environment/)

**Also**

you can use FBGrab.

FBgrab is a framebuffer screenshot program, capturing the linux frambuffer and converting it to a png-picture. FBGrab is delivered as is without any warranty and license is GPL version 2.

BUT, The last version was in 2004.

For more info about fbgrab check [this](https://github.com/MikeMayer/FBGrab)

Comment: Thank you maythux. Found the answer on the original question as mine was marked as duplicate. But nevertheless with that amount of trouble are wanted to vote it as a good answer.

Comment: Hey, thanks for this answer, but neither work for me. fbgrab says `Error: Couldn't open /dev/fb0.` and snapscreenshot says `/dev/console: Permission denied`. Any idea how to fix?

Comment: UPDATE: I had to add my user to the video group for fbgrab to work. snapscreenshot is still not working though.

Comment: UPDATE: snapscreenshot works as long as the acting user has read permissions for the console you are shooting. The easy thing to do is just run snapscreenshot as root.