# How can I take a screenshot of an application running in a TTY without framebuffering enabled?

Tags: command-line, software-recommendation, tty, screenshot

As the title says, I have an application that I need to run in a TTY. I also need to take a screenshot of it while it's running. How can I take a screenshot of an application running in a TTY without framebuffering enabled?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I take a screenshot of a virtual console?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/12208/can-i-take-a-screenshot-of-a-virtual-console)

Comment: @muru I don't have framebuffering enabled, and I'm also having a hard time enabling it, actually I'm trying to do this in order to debug a problem that might even relate to framebuffering itself

Comment: I suppose taking a photo is not an option?

Comment: And what about http://askubuntu.com/questions/194291/how-to-take-screenshot-in-a-tty-terminal ?

Comment: you can enable framebuffer like so: `echo "FRAMEBUFFER=y" | sudo tee /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/splash; sudo update-initramfs -u` reboot.

Comment: @muru Nope, `./configure`, `make install`, it compiles but doesn't add a `man` page, nor there are usage indications on the answer you linked or on the site, I have no idea of how to use it

Comment: @mchid Thanks, at this point I'll give it a try after having answered this

Answer (score 3):

You can use ttyrec

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ttyrec
```

http://0xcc.net/ttyrec/index.html.en

There are a a few options, look for

```
ttyrec -u
```

Which allows you to record to a zip file you can later unzip and should be able to play in a regular terminal later that you can easily take a screenshot of.

Comment: Or use ttygif to convert directly to a GIF.