# How to take a screenshot of a TTY while unable to execute code in it?

Tags: gnome, tty, console, screenshot

I want to run something in one TTY and then take a screenshot of it from another TTY (because it won't let me run something else in the same TTY that I am running the thing in that I want to take the screenshot of), is this possible? I looked at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12208/can-i-take-a-screenshot-of-a-virtual-console) but it appears to be only from the current TTY. I don't mind if I do it from the same TTY though with some sort of clever delay or something, but I just can't think of how to do something like that. I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18.

Comment: found it: http://askubuntu.com/questions/12208/can-i-take-a-screenshot-of-a-virtual-console

Comment: @Rinzwind: Yes, I know, that's the question I linked to in my question.